# Grails Spring Security UI Plugin - Does It Support Groups?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm getting ready to implement the Spring Security UI plugin (we've already implemented the Spring Security Core plugin).  I know the core plugin has support for users, roles, and groups, however, I don't see any mention of groups in the Spring Security UI plugin's documentation.  Does Spring Security UI plugin not support creating, edition, etc. groups?  Anyone tried adding this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

A late response, but I had the same question so I thought I would just try it.
I have just attempted this myself and I believe the the answer is **No**. (out of the box)

The spring security ui plugin doesn't take the groups into consideration.  If you try to edit a user

```
myapp/user/edit/1
```

you will recieve some sort of error like:

```
Class groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
No such property: authority for class: com.myapp.security.SecGroup Possible solutions: authorities
```

I'm curious if you found a way around this? Or we will have to customize the the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As Julian noted the UI doesn't provide support for groups out of the box.  To avoid the error you can do the following (customize the plugin):

Copy the User controller into your project to override the plugin's controller:

```
grails s2ui-override user <your-package-for-controller>
```

Copy the "buildUserModel" from the plugin code in UserController and edit the userRoleNames field:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class UserController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.UserController {

  protected Map buildUserModel(user) {
    ...
    // Added so that when using groups doesn't cause an error
    Set userRoleNames
    if (SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.useRoleGroups) {
        String groupAuthorityFieldName = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.authority.groupAuthorityNameField
        userRoleNames = user[authoritiesPropertyName].collect { it[groupAuthorityFieldName].collect { it[authorityFieldName] } }
    } else {
        userRoleNames = user[authoritiesPropertyName].collect { it[authorityFieldName] }
    }
    ...
}
```